# Not able to create my Xpath

Tags: xpath

How do i create my own xpath from the following..

```
<article class="sessionBox sessionAndTest boxShadow1 borderColor subPhysics" ng-repeat="data in sessionList | limitTo:listingLimit" ng-click="goToSessionPage(data)" my-repeat-directive="">
```

Comment: xpath for `<article>` element inside a xml is what you're looking for? please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example go for the `ng-click` attribute like this:

```
//article[@ng-click='goToSessionPage(data)']
```

Comment: Yes. `[@someattribute]` works for any. With no value, it merely tests the existence of the attribute.

Comment: @joshi what exactly is not working? please provide the code you're using and the error message you're getting